# Использование subprocess для открытия файла

Tags: python, subprocess

Есть данная строка в коде:

```
subprocess.run(file_for_open, shell=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Не понимаю почему, но он не открывает файлы, в пути которых есть пробел. Но, если этот же пусть записать напрямую в subprocess.run, то он без проблем его откроет.
Как можно решить проблему с пробелами, когда вводишь путь до файла через другую переменную?

Comment: `file_for_open` покажите, при котором выбивает, прямо  перед этой строкой `print` сделайте

Comment: Если вы используете `shell=True`, значит пробел является спецсимволом для этого самого шелла. Зачем вам шелл?

Comment: D:\Ucheba\Новая папка\Линукс 1\LR1.pdf как пример, но в любом месте, где есть пробел выдаёт что-то не понятное

Comment: А без shell=True всё время пишет, что не удаётся найти файл, а если вставить путь напрямую, то ошибка: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32

Comment: Ошибка [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32 при: 
path = "D:\\Ucheba\\Новая папка\\Не принял\\Линукс 1\\LR1.pdf"
subprocess.run(path)

Попробовал создать файл с переменной, ошибку не выдал, может ли быть эта ошибка, если я пусть получаю из txt файла?

Comment: @Keory либо используйте `r"path\to\file"`

Comment: кто же через шел pdf открывает?

Comment: r"path\to\file" ошибка, что не может найти файл

Comment: нужно открывать не только pdf файлы, поэтому и shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл надо открывать через start

```
import subprocess, os, platform

filepath = "D:\\Ucheba\\Новая папка\\Линукс 1\\LR1.pdf"

if platform.system() == 'Darwin':       # macOS
    subprocess.call(('open', filepath))
elif platform.system() == 'Windows':    # Windows
    os.startfile(filepath)
else:                                   # linux variants
    subprocess.call(('xdg-open', filepath))
```

Или к одному стилю

```
import subprocess, platform

filepath = "C:\\Users\\eri\\Downloads\\Заявление на получение КЭП.pdf"

if platform.system() == 'Darwin':       # macOS
    subprocess.call(('open', filepath))
elif platform.system() == 'Windows':    # Windows
    subprocess.call(('start', "", filepath), shell=True)
else:                                   # linux variants
    subprocess.call(('xdg-open', filepath))
```

Comment: Просто открывает cmd, а сам файл нет

Comment: С  os.startfile работает точно

Comment: @Keory, поправил вариант с subprocess

Comment: Спасибо, с subprocess.call(('start', "", filepath), shell=True) заработало